# Run fastapi with gunicorn causes segmentation fault

Tags: openssl, fastapi, gunicorn, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Trying to deploy a model on Vertex ai with gunicorn running a fasapi app i get the following error:

> ERROR 2023-11-28T16:04:40.775271177Z E1128 16:04:40.775010808 42
> ssl_transport_security_utils.cc:105] Corruption detected. ERROR
> 2023-11-28T16:04:40.775349140Z E1128 16:04:40.775054357 42
> ssl_transport_security_utils.cc:61] error:100003fc:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC ERROR
> 2023-11-28T16:04:40.775360107Z E1128 16:04:40.775060004 42
> secure_endpoint.cc:305] Decryption error: TSI_DATA_CORRUPTED INFO
> 2023-11-28T16:04:40.777589553Z Booting worker with pid: %s ERROR
> 2023-11-28T16:04:40.828513383Z E1128 16:04:40.828315995 114
> ev_epoll1_linux.cc:819] ASSERTION FAILED:
> gpr_atm_no_barrier_load(&g_active_poller) != (gpr_atm)worker ERROR
> 2023-11-28T16:04:40.865352392Z E1128 16:04:40.865182989 115
> ev_epoll1_linux.cc:819] ASSERTION FAILED:
> gpr_atm_no_barrier_load(&g_active_poller) != (gpr_atm)worker ERROR
> 2023-11-28T16:04:41.448427915Z Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Command is:

```
 gunicorn -w 2 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --log-level debug --bind 0.0.0.0:80
```

This happens on gunicorn 21.2.0 and does not happen on 19.7 (Workaround..)